# EF6 Code First Relationship (MVC 5 app)

Tags: entity-framework, relational-database

I have following classes

```
public class Address
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public AddressType AddressType { get; set; } // (  Enum -- {Correspondence, Billing, Other}
        public string AddressLine {get; set;}               
        public string Town {get; set;}                       
        public string Region {get; set;}                   
        public string PostCode { get; set; }               
        public string Country {get; set;}

    }
}

 public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LegalName { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } // Addresses (Correspondence, billing address,physicalAddress etc)

}


public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    }

 public ActionResult AddCompany()
        {
            Company Co = new Company();
            Address postAddress = new Address() { AddressType = Helper.Enums.AddressType.PostAddress };
            Address physicalAddress = new Address() { AddressType = Helper.Enums.AddressType.PhysicalAddress };
            org.Addresses = new List<Address>();
            org.Addresses.Add(postAddress);
            org.Addresses.Add(physicalAddress);
}
```

I want Address to be added when ever I add Person or Company, but could not do so using Seed method.

EF creates CompanyID in Addresses table why, I want only one way relations, please help

Comment: You put `Address` collection on `Company`, that means one company has many addresses, or in other words many addresses can refer to a company, that's why `Address` needs to have `Company_ID` column so that it can refer to `Company` table, probably what you want is to put collection of `Company` and collection of `Person` on Address, or a one-to-one relationship

Comment: Thank you, for each enum company will have one address and same with the person, I was thinking to have address ID and enum for filtering but, I am wrong here. I probably need new tables (CompanyAddresses and PersonAddresses) i-e (AddressID and PersonID)/ CompanyID) ?

Comment: so a single company can have 3 addresses, right? Correspondence address, billing address, physical address. And so does person? If that so, your relationship and code are correct.

Comment: But in the SQL address table there is PersonID and CompanyID, each table row will have one null value which I think is wrong?

Comment: the address entities belongs to company and person, right? that means address table needs to have person_id and company_id

Comment: What if I require only Company and Person table to to know about address Id but Address table  just have address details but no Foreign keys of Person or company?

Comment: Principal (company and person) can't have foreign key to Dependent (address). Imagine SalesOrderHeader and SalesOrderDetail relationship, and SalesOrderHeader has SalesOrderDetail_ID column, that doesn't make sense. Unless Address is created first (and saved to database), then when a Company is created, the user can choose which address to used. The same Address can be used by another Company or Person. In that case Address is Principal, and Company and Person are Dependent. Or perhaps what you want is [one to one relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/).

Comment: Thank you, Its clear now. I need to create property for each address type in company and person table for example public Address  BillingAddress {get; set;} and public Address CorrespondenceAddress {get; set;}